# Let $g : \Bbb N \times \Bbb N \to\Bbb N \times \Bbb N$ defined as $g(m,n) = (m + n,m - n)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

Determine if $g$ is

1. injective;
2. surjective;
3. bijective.

Question on a recent test regarding one-to-one and onto functions. Was very difficult for me, could not even begin to answer either. This is a proofs class, much help would be appreciated.

Comment: What are your thoughts so far? :)

Comment: What is the point of downvotes here? If OP has no idea even where to start, it's not surprising he's not able to show any work.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a well-defined function.  Is $g(1,2)$ an element of $\mathbb N\times\mathbb N$?

Comment: @nik: You can always show *something*. Suggested lines of thought: Do I understand the terms in the question? (If not, ask a question about that instead). Can I solve similar but simpler problems? (If so, maybe try showing an example)

Comment: @BenMillwood: If the OP could answer these questions on his own, chances are he wouldn't need to ask this question here. Proofs classes are notoriously hard for first-timers, learning good mathematical habits isn't easy, and IMO it's worthy of a Q&A here. In any case downvotes won't help.

Comment: There are so many questions out just bluntly stating the problem to be solved and nothing else, with no or maybe one downvote. I find it peculiar to see three downvotes on this one. To me, this question is fine (except for the part where $g$ is not really well-defined).

Comment: @nik: It is very easy to answer my questions with "no". To leave them unanswered altogether leaves me with no idea where to start if I really want to be a teacher and not just the proverbial back of the textbook.

Comment: @k.stm: I don't read every question, so naturally most of them escape my boundless and mighty wrath.

Comment: @BenMillwood: I didn't explain myself well, sorry. Yes, it's easy to answer them, once you know that you need to ask yourself this question. What I mean is that it's not necessarily easy to answer them on one's own, that is without prompting.

Comment: @nik: Well, fair enough. To which I answer that my downvote isn't meant to imply that the questioner failed as a person and deserves judgement and suffering. I just think their question is not the kind of question I want to see more of on MSE.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

**(Surjecticity)** Can you solve this
$$g(m,n)=(p,q)\iff\left\{\begin{array}\\
m+n=p\\
m-n=q
\end{array}\right.\;\;?$$
and what happens if $p+q$ is odd? .

**(Injectivity)** In the case $p+q$ is even express $m$ and $n$ with $p$ and $q$. What you can deduce?

Comment: I think I just have a fundamental misunderstanding of this topic. What does it mean to solve g(m,n) = (p,q,) <=> ...

Comment: We have $g(m,n)=(m+n,m-n)$ so if we assume that $g(m,n)=(p,q)$ then $(m+n,m-n)=(p,q)$ hence $m+n=p$ and $m-n=q$ and solve this system means express $m$ and $n$ with $p$ and $q$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $2m=(m+n)+(m-n), 2n=(m+n)-(m-n)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint on surjectivity: if $(x,y)=g(m,n)$ then $x-y$ is even.

Answer (score 1):

For this kind of questions, you really need to stick to the definitions as much as possible. Especially if you don't know where to start. You can't do anything without the definition. So let's begin.

First, a function is defined to be bijective if it is at the same time surjective and injective. So we'll get an answer to (c) as soon as we have an answer to (a) and (b).

For (a), an injective function is one where $g(m,n) = g(m', n') \Rightarrow (m,n) = (m', n')$. So given $m,n,m',n'$ such that $\begin{cases} m + n = m' + n' \\ m - n = m' - n' \end{cases}$, can you show or not if $m=m'$ and $n=n'$?

For (b), a function is surjective if every element $(a,b)$ can be written as $g(m,n)$ for some $(m,n)$, depending on $a$ and $b$ of course. So if you choose $a$ and $b$, can you find or not $m$ and $n$ such that $\begin{cases} m + n = a \\ m - n = b \end{cases}$?